# Отделить в hibernate @GeneratedValue id друг от друга (Свой кастомный ID)

Tags: hibernate

Такая проблема:

Когда я использую:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) или @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long id;
```

У меня создается единая таблица `hibernate_sequence` в которой записываются все ID в колонку `next_val` и при добавлении данных, все колонки увеличивываются на 1. Как сделать так, чтобы для каждой таблицы(сущности) был свой ID, который увеличивывается на 1 и не зависил бы от других таблиц?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Hibernate есть возможность создания кастомных ID.

Ниже приведенный материал основан на прочтенных мною статей в интернете в том числе [данной статьи, на которую я опирался в своем ответе](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/)

Вот примитивный вариант её реализации:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "player_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="player_generator", sequenceName = "player_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
```

Итак:
`generator = "player_generator"` - Это названия генератора, который будем использовать (название может быть любое. Главное в кавычках =) )
`name="player_generator"` - Название кастомного генератора
`sequenceName = "player_seq"` - это под каким названием будет создана таблица в базе данных
`allocationSize = 1` (**Optional**. Можно не писать) - Это на сколько будет увеличиваться ваш id. [По дефолту - на 50]
`initialValue = 1` (**Optional**. Можно не писать) - Это с какого числа начинается отсчет. [По дефолту - с 1]