# Проблемы с определением простых ключей на Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Хочу написать логику работы с событиями, которые приходят из внешнего источника. Обработка события такая:

- Получить событие, сохранить его в таблицу постгрес.
- По крону извлечь все записи о собятиях из этой таблицы и отправить их по емейлу
- При каждой успешной отправке соответствующуу события удаляется.

Я написал такой энтити-класс:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_warning_events")
public class InvoiceWarningEvent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "invoice_uid")
    @JsonProperty
    private String invoiceUid;

    @Column(name = "invoice_number")
    @JsonProperty
    private String invoiceNumber;

    @Column(name ="company_msp")
    @JsonProperty
    private String companyMSP;

    @Column(name = "error_message")
    @JsonProperty
    private String errorMessage;
```

Первая проблема возникла, когда я написал `JpaRepository`. Записи из таблицы считывались, но метод  `invoiceWarningRepository.delete(evt);` ничего не удалял.

Тогда я попробовал повесить на `@Id`-поле аннотации `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` и `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. В первом случае возникла ошибка:

> Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown
>   integral data type for ids : java.lang.String

Во втором случае получаю ошибку

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [invoice_uid]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Дело в том, что поле invoice_uid должно быть уникальным, в базе оно определено как primary key. Это нужно для того, чтобы множество событий об одном и том же инвойсе приводило к появлению только одной записи, которая постоянно обновляется.

Как убрать эту ошибку?

А еще, каким методом можно реализовать операцию insert or update, если запись уже существует?

Comment: Получилось решить проблему?

Comment: @Antonio112009, да, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Про удаление:
JpaRepository имеет только 2 метода: deleteById and deleteAll.
Посмотри данную ссылку: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-delete

Отсюда тебе стоит брать ID строки и удалять по ID

2) Тебе нужно будет иметь 2 ID лучше:
- Id строки в таблице
- Id инвойса

то есть:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "InvoiceWarningEvent_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="InvoiceWarningEvent_generator", sequenceName = "InvoiceWarningEvent_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "invoice_uid")
    @JsonProperty
    private String invoiceUid;
```

3) Про generatodvalue - попробуй использовать кастомную) [смотри это тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994237/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-hibernate-generatedvalue-id-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-id/994238#994238)