# Как реализовать relation table с дополнительным полем?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Есть сущность категории и сущность язык. У категории может быть несколько языков. 
Как реализовать таким образом, чтобы у категории было только определенное количество id, но много вариантов category_name. Какое отношение будет правильно применить? Может нужно добавить дополнительное поле в связующую таблицу и как это сделать?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Category {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToMany
   private List<Language> languages;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_language")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "mnemo")
    private String mnemo;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Category> categories;
}
```

Comment: прочитал раз 10 что нужно - не понял

Comment: Представьте, что у вас есть категория. И у нее есть поле `name`. Так же эта категория может быть на пяти языках. Как лучше сделать, чтобы избежать отдельной записи в таблице с категориями на каждый язык. Чтобы у одной записи категории было пять `name` на разных языках. Я думаю, что поможет только отдельная таблица с `id` категории, `id` языка и `name` категории.

Comment: @PavelRodionov смогли найти ответ?

Comment: Пока сделал дополнительную сущность с ссылкой на категорию и с ссылкой на язык + поле с `name` категории.

Answer (score 0):

[Другие примеры аннотации можно найти тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993198/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-onetomany-onetoone-manytomany-manytoone-hibernate/993199#993199)

[Про один из вариантов реализации кастомного ID я рассказываю тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994237/275232)

Ваш вариант можно реализовать с @OneToMany анотацией (`unidirectional`).
Почему `Unidirectional` Зачем от второй таблички запрашивать первую, когда можно просто в одну сторону?

Идея такова:

#### Category.java:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "category_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="category_generator", sequenceName = "category_seq", allocationSize = 1)
   private Long id;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
   private List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addLanguage(Language language) {
       languages.add(language);
   }

   public void removeLanguage(Language language) {
       languages.remove(language);
   }
}
```

#### Language.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_language")
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "language_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="language_generator", sequenceName = "t_language_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String mnemo;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```