# Генерация уникального id Hibernate Java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Есть таблица в БД PostgreSql. У этой таблицы есть ограничение на уникальность для id. Сохраняю сущности в БД посредством Hibernate.

Код Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cinema_movie")
public class Cinema_Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "cinema_id")
    private String cinemaId;

    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private String movieId;
```

Геттеры и сеттеры, плюс конструктор прилагаются. Не писал для сокращения кода.

Код сохранения в БД:

```
public void save() {
        CinemaMovie cinema_movie = new CinameMovie();
        cinema_movie.setCinemaId("random");
        cinema_movie.setMovieId("random")
        session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.save(cinema_movie); 
    }
```

Ну и в HibernateSessionFactoryUtil ничего особенного нет:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        logger.debug("Start method getSessionFactory() at HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.class");
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Cinema_Movie.class);
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error at method getSessionFactory() at HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.class: ", e);
            }
        }
        logger.debug("End of method getSessionFactory() at HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.class");
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

И соответственно, метод save() вызывается переодически в разное время в программе. Изменения в БД в данную таблицу вносились руками, удалялись некоторые записи, т.к. программа только на стадии разработки.

**Вопрос в следующем:**

Как происходит генерация уникальных значений в Hibernate, и почему переодически я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности
```

?

А так же, как избежать данной ошибки, т.е. чтобы Hibernate точно гененрировал уникальные ID, которых еще нет в БД? Только дополнительной проверкой? Или сделать другой primary key, который самому генерировать? Или же есть какая то возможность исключения такой ошибки с помощью инструментов Hibernate?

Comment: Лучше используйте `GenerationType.AUTO`, чтобы Hibernate мог выбрать стратегию генерации ключей наиболее подходящую к используемой базе, или `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` если хотите явно указать наиболее подходящий для PostgreSQL вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оригинал ответа [можно найти тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994237/275232).

В Hibernate есть возможность создания кастомных ID.

Вот примитивный вариант её реализации:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "player_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="player_generator", sequenceName = "player_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
```

Итак:
`generator = "player_generator"` - Это названия генератора, который будем использовать (название может быть любое. Главное в кавычках =) )
`name="player_generator"` - Название кастомного генератора
`sequenceName = "player_seq"` - это под каким названием будет создана таблица в базе данных
`allocationSize = 1` (**Optional**. Можно не писать) - Это на сколько будет увеличиваться ваш id. [По дефолту - на 50]
`initialValue = 1` (**Optional**. Можно не писать) - Это с какого числа начинается отсчет. [По дефолту - с 1]

---

Также [на данном сайте](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/) рассказываются про разные стратегии:

- Auto
- Sequence
- identity

Comment: Лучше перенести все важно из ссылок в ответ

Comment: @Antonio112009 Как я понимаю, раз автор добавляет записи в базу вручную, то в генераторе ему нужно, например, `initialValue = 1000`; а ручками добавлять записи, имеющие id < 1000. В противном случае это его проблему не решит.

Comment: @golubtsoff Вручную или нет - мы этого не знаем. Мой ответ направлен на то, чтобы показать разные варианты решения его проблемы. Если ему не подойдет основной мой ответ, то на сайте, который я указал под ответом, он найдет другие варианты решения (+ объяснение)

Comment: @Antonio112009 `Изменения в БД в данную таблицу вносились руками, удалялись некоторые записи, т.к. программа только на стадии разработки.` Я думаю, это и сбило счётчик генерации id, раз сами id вводились вручную, а не генерировались базой.

Comment: @golubtsoff, Вы правы, именно это и сбило. И вопрос был направлен на способы исключения данной ситуации. Так сказать "защиту от дурака". Мало ли, что может произойти. А такого происходить для уникальных значений не должно.

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать стратегию increment. Она очень неэффективная, но должна решить вашу проблему (хотя бы на время разработки). При этом каждый раз при вставке сущности будет происходить обращение к базе для чтения последнего id.
Для настройки надо определить генератор id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cinema_movie")
public class Cinema_Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private int id;
```

Так как он может использоваться сразу в нескольких сущностях, определим его на уровне пакета. Создадим файл package-info.java в пакете с сущностями:

*package-info.java*

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
        name = "ID_GENERATOR",
        strategy = "increment",
        parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                        name = "sequence_name",
                        value = "MY_SEQUENCE"
                )
        }
)
package com.project.entities; // имя пакета
```