# JPA связь моделей данных

Tags: java, spring, jpa

есть такие модели:

1. Отдел:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "department_name")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "department_description")
    private String departmentDescription;
}
```

2. Сотрудник (пользователь)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "users_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "user_surname")
    private String userSurname;

    @Column(name = "user_phone")
    private String userPhone;

    @Column(name = "user_department")
    private Department userDepartment;

    @Column(name = "user_login")
    private String userLogin;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String userPassword;
}
```

Связь в базе данных: У одного отдела есть множество сотрудников, так при связи в java выдаёт ошибку

> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.polagaev.denis.rcpodrestfullwebservice.models.Department, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user_department)]

Пытался связывать

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Тут мой столбец")
```

Но не помогло) Подскажите пожалуйста как связать эти таблицы между собой. Спасибо.

Comment: Чекни данный вопрос. Опираться на него не стоит. Просто для общего понятия) [ссылка на SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993198/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-onetomany-onetoone-manytomany-manytoone-hibernate)

Comment: @Antonio112009 Вариант bidirectional:
*Профессор на курсе может узнавать информацию о студентах, в тоже самое время студенты могут узнавать информацию о Профессоре * вроде же он? мне надо чтобы я мог узнать в отделе всех сотрудников в неём, а в сотруднике - информацию об отделе??? Будет здорово, если напишете а в ответ на вопрос, как сделать, я отмечу)

Comment: Да, вроде он) Сейчас напишу. Чтобы было все честно - проверьте, что код компилируется

Comment: А департамент будет только 1 или несколько? и если несколько, то сотрудники одного департамента могут работать в другом?

Comment: От вашего ответа (на мой вопрос выше) будет зависеть использование той или иной аннотации

Comment: @Antonio112009 У пользователя департмент будет только 1. сотрудники не могут работать в другом.

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ если он решает вашу проблему.

Comment: @Denis Тогда вы, как и я, правильную аннотацию выбрали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Оффтоп:

Для данного ответа я использую материалы, написанные мною [в данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/275232)

В своем ответе я использую библиотеку [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) для автоматической генерации getters/setters, constructor. Более подробно про Lombok [я написал тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993199/275232)

Безопасно ли использование Lombok в проекте? [Да. Вот материал на этот счет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852091/is-it-safe-to-use-project-lombok)

P.S. Для удобства работы с ним в IDE, желательно установить plugin `lombok`

---

### Ответ:

1. О `@GeneratedValue` и `@SequenceGenerator` прочитать [можно тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994237/275232). Скажу сразу, другого "лучшего способа" я не придумал для раздельной автогенирации следующего id, да еще с кастомными настройками!
2. Тип данных для `id` лучше использовать `Long` ( или `long`)
3. `@Column(name = "department_name")` - не обязательно прописывать имя колонки. Если У тебя переменная записана как `MyBestFriends`, то при создании таблиц, `hibernate` запишет в БД это как `my_best_friends`.
4. Как я понимаю, департамент важнее сотрудников, поэтому пусть первый объект будет родителем, а другой [сотрудники] будут детьми.
5. Подробную работу про `@OneToMany` аннотацию можно [прочесть тут](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
6. Почему вместо `List<>`, я использую `Set<>`? Почему не пишу `CascadeType.ALL`?
   Посмотри [Update 11.09.2019 вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993199/275232)
7. mappedBy = "depatment". Откуда взялось `department`? В классе `User.java` есть строка `private Department department;`. Я просто взял и указал на данную переменную.

   > После того, как мы определили сторону-владельца отношений, Hibernate уже имеет всю информацию, необходимую для отображения этих отношений в нашей базе данных. Чтобы сделать эту ассоциацию двунаправленной, все, что нам нужно сделать, это определить сторону ссылки. Обратная или ссылочная сторона просто отображается на сторону-владельца. (Google Translate. Лень переводить самому.)
8. `@ToString(exclude="")` - зачем эта аннотация? При попытке отобразить объекты в `System.out.println()`, вы можете натолкнуться на StackOverflow exception. Происходит это из-за бесконечной рекурсии (User часть Department, который содержит информацию о данном User, а User содержит информацию о данном Department и т.д.), поэтому в exclude мы пишем объект, который не хотим отображать да бы избежать данной ошибки.

#### Department.java:

```java
@Data
//Две ниже аннотации - это для создания конструктора. Их можно убрать, если не нужно прописывать что-то в конструктор
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "professor")
@Table
class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "department_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="department_generator", sequenceName = "seq_department", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String departmentName;

    @Column
    private String departmentDescription;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "department",
            cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    Set<User> user = new HashMap<>();

    /*
    Нам надо создать "рекурсию". Отдел ссылается на сотрудника, а сотрудник на департамент.
    Поэтому для добавления новых сотрудников используем методы ниже.
     */
    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
        user.setDepartment(this);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        users.remove(user);
        user.setDepartment(null);
    }

}
```

#### User.java

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "department")
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="users_generator", sequenceName = "seq_users", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "users_id")
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String userName;

    @Column
    private String userSurname;

    @Column
    private String userPhone;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")

    @Column
    private String userLogin;

    @Column
    private String userPassword;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не удивительно, что не помогло:)

Ошибка от того, что Ваше поле `Users#userDepartment`, не имея специальных аннотаций для установки отношений между сущностями, рассматривается как обычное поле с неизвестным науке типом `Department`.

Надо примерно так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_department")
    private Department department;

    ...

}
```

`ManyToOne` - вот что заставит hibernate распознать в этом несчастном поле попытку связать сущности!

`name` из `JoinColumn` указывает столбец в таблице `users`, который ссылается на столбец `id` в таблице `department`.

И обратное направление, если Вам оно так надо:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
class Department {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private List<Users> users;

    ...

}
```

`mappedBy` - это указатель вовсе не столбца из таблицы, а свойство класса `Users`, которое устанавливает прямую связь этого двунаправленного отношения.

А `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` - это правильно. Если ликвидировать отдел, так со всеми дармоедами сразу разом:) На самом деле конечно зависит от ситуации, и в большинстве не надо так делать.

И вот Вам в помощь: 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence

Comment: происходит цикличный вывод.

Comment: @Denis О каком цикличном выводе речь? Само по себе описание сущностей ничего никуда не выводит. Или выводит? Ничего не понимаю.