# Hibernate: ошибка сохранения экземпляра сущности

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

Исходный код:

```
Transaction tx = null;
try (final var session = HibernateSessionFactory.getInstance().openSession()) {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(c); // где с - экземпляр класса InternalDatabase
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("cannot save DB connection: {}", ex.getMessage());
    if (tx != null && (tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE || tx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.MARKED_ROLLBACK)) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception nex) {
            logger.error(nex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> 19:26:28.595 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR
>   com.xxx.DatabaseConnectionsController - cannot save DB connection:
>   class org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 cannot be cast to
>   class java.lang.Long (org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 is
>   in module org.hibernate.orm.core@6.0.0.Alpha2 of loader 'app';
>   java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

InternalDatabase:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "internal_database")
public class InternalDatabase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "conn_str", nullable = false)
    private String connectionString;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "query")
    private String query;

    public InternalDatabase() { }
}
```

В начале таблицу создавал руками:

```
-- Entity: InternalDatabase
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INTERNAL_DATABASE (
    ID          INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    CONN_STR    VARCHAR(300)    NOT NULL,
    USERNAME    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    QUERY       VARCHAR(500)    DEFAULT ''
);

ALTER TABLE "INTERNAL_DATABASE"
    ADD CONSTRAINT INTERNAL_DATABASE_NAME UNIQUE (NAME);
```

, потом добавил опцию `hbm2ddl.auto` в конфигурационный файл Hibernate - таблица создалась автоматически, ошибка - осталась.

hibernate.cfg.xml выглядит так:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:./xa;ifexists=true</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!--        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->

        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.Permission"/>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.Role"/>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.InternalDatabase"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Env.: macOS 10.13, 10.14; JVM 12; Hibernate 6.0.0Alpha2; H2

MWE: https://github.com/isnullxbh/hhh-13630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. если используешь Maven - установи database connection provider. Лично я использую `hikariCP`, но многие используют `C3P0`(?!?). Я считаю, что hikari быстрее.
   P.S. Версию выбери актуальную для тебя)

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. Я бы порекомендовал бы следующие настройки `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

#### hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:./xa;ifexists=true</property>

        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">20000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">300000</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <!--<property name="show_sql">true</property>-->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>-->

        <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>


        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.Permission"/>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.Role"/>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.entity.InternalDatabase"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

3. Вместо `GenerationType.IDENTITY` рекомендую использовать `Sequence`, да еще кастомный)) [В своем вопросе я постарался четко описать как настроить данную вещь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994237/275232). Ответ в том вопросе основывается [на материале с данного сайта](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/)
4. Поставь следующие настройки `HibernateUtil`:

#### HibernateUtil.java:

```java
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

5. Пример сохранения объекта в таблицу:

```
public class UserRepository {
    private Transaction transaction = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private User user = null;

    //Save Single User
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.saveOrUpdate(user);

            transaction.commit();

            session.clear();
            session.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

6. Почему `saveOrUpdate` вместо `save`? Чтобы не создавать два метода, который один сохраняет данные, а другой изменяет их. Проще через один метод реализовывать
7. `@Table(name = "internal_database")` - не обязательно прописывать имя колонки/таблицы. Если у Вас переменная записана как `MyBestFriends`, то при создании таблиц/колонки, hibernate запишет в БД это как `my_best_friends`.
8. (Optional) Так же `@Column` можно не упоминать, потому что любые переменные в классе hibernate, как я лично заметил, и так считаются за колонку. (Если только вы не используете аннотацию @transient). Данный факт я не могу подтвердить никаким ресурсом... Так что `@Column` лучше все-таки писать
9. **@Column(nullable = false) vs @NotNull.** Стоит использовать `@NotNull`, потому что в таком случае проверка на содержание `null`-объекта происходит перед отправкой данных в БД. [Данную информацию прочитать можно тут](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-whats-the-difference-between-column-nullable-false-and-notnull/)
10. (Optional) Точно не уверен, но если у вас `private Sting name` - уникален, возможно можно добавить к нему аннотацию `@NaturalId`. Немного об этом [написано тут](https://thoughts-on-java.org/naturalid-good-way-persist-natural-ids-hibernate/).
11. (Дополнительно) Если есть вопросы по аннотациям - можно прочитать [данный вопрос с ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/275232). Пока ответ не идеальный.

В итоге вот как я примерно вижу вашу сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class InternalDatabase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "intdata_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="intdata_generator", sequenceName = "seq_intdata", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "conn_str",)
    private String connectionString;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String query;

    public InternalDatabase() { }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @isnullxbh вы протестили мой ответ? Все заработало?

Comment: Да, конечно, иначе бы я не принял его, как правильный :) Спасибо! 3 пункт мне очень помог.

Comment: @isnullxbh я заметил еще небольшие "недочеты" в Enitity... Это огромной роли не играет в  вашем код, но покажу еще один вариант написания его.

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, то конечно, буду рад узнать.

Comment: @isnullxbh обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! 9-10 пункты мне показались интересными! Буду разбираться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98925/discussion-between-isnullxbh-and-antonio112009).

Answer (score 1):

Если мне не изменяет память, то здесь проблема заключается в том, что генератор не может сгенерировать идентификатор без физического инсерта, а использует своего рода маркер.
В моем случае похожий код работал для Oracle, но не работал для H2.

Как один из способов решения попробуйте использовать `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`, либо вообще `@GeneratedValue`. Если по какой-то причине предложенные варианты не заработают, то используйте другие типы генераторов, например, `@GenericGenerator` (там должно быть все гладко).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!