# Не обновляются сущности @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mvc, orm

Есть 2 сущности:
`Order.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name = "price")
private int price;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade= CascadeType.ALL
)
private Set<Master> masters;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "garage_id")
private Garage garage;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private Client client;

........... 
}
```

и

`Master.java`

```
Entity
@Table(name = "masters")
public class Master extends Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private int id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Order.class,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(name = "current_order_id")
private Order currentOrder;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "masters",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
private Set<Garage> garage;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "orders_and_masters",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "master_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
)
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

.................
}
```

Если сделать update заказа, то сет с мастерами не изменится.
Также, если сделать update мастера, то `currentOrder` тоже не изменится.
Ошибка, я думаю, в связях. Ибо передаю правильно и в дебаге прямо перед выполнением update, у сущности все поля правильно изменились, даже сет с мастерами у заказа.
Остальные поля, то есть `Garage`, `Client` обновятся и с ними всё хорошо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117153/many-to-many-java-spring?noredirect=1#comment1928903_1117153

Comment: @Antonio112009 я может быть плохо вас понял, но вы предлагаете ознакомится со статьёй и переписать всё?

Comment: @Antonio112009, я сейчас заметил, что у мастера ```currentOrder``` как ManyToOne замаппен, так что пробелма не в ManyToMany

Comment: `Set<>` лучше не использовать. Читать тут - https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-avoid-hibernates-multiplebagfetchexception/

Comment: 2 - у вас нету рекурсии объектов. Вам в программе надо указать, что Мастер ссылается на Ордер, а Ордер - на мастерс. читать это - https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: А в ссылке, которую я скинул - это пример того как надо правильно реализовывать

Comment: @Antonio112009, Я использовать ```Set<>``` начал, чтобы можно было без проблем лениво тянуть из базы сразу несколько связанных коллекций

Comment: @Antonio112009 как раз после этой ссылки всё и переписал на ```Set<>```, в статье :```You can avoid the MultipleBagFetchException by using a Set instead of a List.```

Comment: Я ошибся статьей. То, что я скинул - за 2013 год. Вот за 2019 - https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825218

Comment: @Antonio112009, как я понял из прочитанного, ```Set<>``` всё равно порождает декартово произведение записей(но почему?) и потому при запросе нужно использовать несколько запросов. Это дороже, но вроде как правильнее. Но это разве мой случай? При ```get``` у меня нормально всё приходит, а при update ничего в логи не пишет, обновляет как надо другие сущности, но не мастера и заказ(и их общие поля)

Comment: @Antonio112009, я не создаю записей с дополнительными сущностями.
Я вначале заполняю примитивные поля, а потом через update сетаю энтити.
То есть я создаю мастеров(на каждого запрос), клиента, пустой заказ.
Далее через update отправляю Dto заказа, где любые связанные сущности заменены на ```Integer``` и ```Set<Integer>```.Потом нахожу ранее созданный заказ по id, делаю доп. запросы чтобы достать нужных мастеров и клиента и просто сетаю в заказ. А заказ отправляю в ```entityManager.update(order)```.
Никаких дубликатов, так почему не обновляется?